# Unable to connect to mysql database with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to my mysql database but nothing seem to work out for me.
I'm going crazy, I've searched the internet for about 3 hours straight and didn't find anything that is any use to me. Please, can anyone help me?

This is the code I have so far:

```
public bool tryLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            MySqlConnection con =
                new MySqlConnection("Server=159.253.0.3;Database=dbname;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"); // Removed the login info.
            MySqlCommand cmd =
                new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_name = '" + username + "' AND user_pass = '" + password +
                                 "';");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This is the error I keep getting:

> Access denied for user
>   'joeysft57_app'@'53569B33.cm-6-7c.dynamic.ziggo.nl' (using password:
>   YES)

Comment: you will not have to do it for every user.. just create a user in database and use its credentials in connection string..

Comment: @RajeshRolen-DotNetDeveloper Do you have any examples? I'm pretty new to mysql :(.

Comment: check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

Comment: very good step by step.. : http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user

Comment: @RajeshRolen-DotNetDeveloper Thanks, I only have 1 more problem, I'm not running the mysql but I'm using one on the internet. Is it still possible?

Comment: if you have valid credentials then just download any mysql client tool(lots of free mysql client tools available) and connect it to your dbserver and run queries over it..

Comment: @RajeshRolen-DotNetDeveloper MySQL Workbench is saying: "Cannot Connect to Database Server". And I'm 100% sure I'm using the correct username and password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13255/discussion-between-rajesh-rolen-dotnet-developer-and-darkshadw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue of permission (rights).. you can confirm it with connecting it with your local db.. if its working with your local db then surely its a issue of permission

Comment: Is there a setting somewhere in phpmyadmin that shows me if remote connections are allowed or not?

Comment: @Darkshadw: you will not have to do it for every user.. just create a user in database and use its credentials in connection string..

Answer (score 0):

I think that your user `joeysft57_app` doesn't have the permission to reach the database from the computer specified.
You need to connect to the administrator interface of your database and give the permission required

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO myAppUser@%  IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON serverdb.* to myAppUser@%
```

or ask the database administrator to do this for you.

EDIT: Changed something, 
first the use of wildcard `%` to let the user connect from any PC 
second defined a generic user that will be used in your connection string, so your users connect all with the same user/password. This of course, is not very good from a security standpoint. But it's you choice.

If the database is on the same machine where your application runs then you could also use `localhost` instead of the `%` shortcut. (more secure)

Comment: Okay, but is it possible to avoid this? Because that means I have to do this for every user that is going to login in this application.